# Device Token not generating in ios 8.1

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, push-notification, ios8.1

[image]
I have implemented push notification generation using the following methods.

```
    if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 8.0)
{
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:[UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:(UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert | UIUserNotificationTypeBadge) categories:nil]];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotifications];
}
else
{
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:
     (UIUserNotificationTypeBadge | UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert)];
}
```

the device token generated correctly normally. But when switch off the Sounds and Badge App Icon and set the alert style as none, (Settings -> App Name -> Notifications) the device token not generating. This issue only occur in iOS 8 devices. In iOS 7 devices it correctly working. Could any one give solution for this.

Comment: if  u disable the notification how to get the device token bro

Comment: No the device token is enabled. Please see the image.

Comment: Well, does the error also occur when you use the methods to register in a distinct way? I might occur that the deprecated method obfuscates the registration process for the app. Please make sure (also if you want to support iOS7 and earlier) that the registers correctly:if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] respondsToSelector:@selector(registerUserNotificationSettings:)])

Comment: @Lepidopteron It correctly working when Sounds and Badge App Icon switches are on

Answer (score 1):

This is more a bug of iOS7. Notification has 3 way to be prompted to the user : Sounds / Badge / Alert.
If you disable sounds and badge and if you set Alert style to None ( i.e. you disable alert ) there is no way to present the notification.

I think this is battery optimisation : if there is no way to notify the user, why registering him to remote notification ?